# Apps Script, convert a Sheet range to Blob

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

Background: 
I'm trying to upload an individual row of data from a Google Sheet and append it to a BigQuery table.

Method: I've been using https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery to do this, but instead of a file of data as the example is, I am using my own sheet with data from a specific row:

```
 var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var currentSheet = file.getSheetByName(name);
  var lastRow = currentSheet.getLastRow()
   var lastC = currentSheet.getLastColumn()
   var rows = currentSheet.getRange(2,1,1,lastC).getValues();
```

"rows" is the row of data to be imported to BQ. I've tried a multitude of things, and according to another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327109/google-apps-script-convert-to-csv), "rowsCSV" makes the 2D array of values CSV.

```
  var rowsCSV = rows.join("\n");

 var data = rowsCSV.getBlob().setContentType('application/octet-stream');
```

Problem: Every time I run the function, I get the error "Cannot find function getBlob in object Blob. " or, "Cannot convert Array to (class)[][]", or "Cannot find function getBlob in object Tue May 16 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST),58072.4,,,,,,,,,,,test ", where the last bit ("Tue May..") is the actual data of the row.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `getBlob` method for an array. You will have to use the `Utilities.newBlob()` to get your blob from a string. You can find the documentation on the same [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newBlob(String,String))

```
 var rowsCSV = rows.join("\n");
 var blob = Utilities.newBlob(rowsCSV, "text/csv")
 Logger.log(blob.getDataAsString())
 var data = blob.setContentType('application/octet-stream');
```

Equivalently you can do this

```
var rowsCSV = rows.join("\n");
var data = Utilities.newBlob(rowsCSV, 'application/octet-stream')
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else viewing this, Jack Brown's answer is correct, you just need to change

`var rows = currentSheet.getRange(2,1,1,lastC).getValues();`

to

`var rows = currentSheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,lastC).getValues();`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the correction given by @JackBrown I have edited my code, however unable to push data to the Big Query. The below code create table, but don't push values.

```
    /**
 * Loads a CSV into BigQuery
 */
function loadCsv() {
  // Replace this value with the project ID listed in the Google
  // Cloud Platform project.
  var projectId = 'master-ad-data';
  // Create a dataset in the BigQuery UI (https://bigquery.cloud.google.com)
  // and enter its ID below.
  var datasetId = 'DataImportFromSpreadsheet';
  // Sample CSV file of Google Trends data conforming to the schema below.
  // https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwzA1Orbvy5WMXFLaTR1Z1p2UDg/edit
  var csvFileId = '17kYH6hP2RlsFeUmwM1v6WOgm2FKrwLTXWDhA2ZLISN8';
  var name = 'Sheet1';

  // Create the table.
  var tableId = 'pets_' + new Date().getTime();
  var table = {
    tableReference: {
      projectId: projectId,
      datasetId: datasetId,
      tableId: tableId
    },
    schema: {
      fields: [
        {name: 'CampaignLabels', type: 'STRING'},
        {name: 'ImpressionShare', type: 'INTEGER'}
      ]
    }
  };
  table = BigQuery.Tables.insert(table, projectId, datasetId);
  Logger.log('Table created: %s', table.id);


  var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var currentSheet = file.getSheetByName(name);
  var lastRow = currentSheet.getLastRow()
  var lastC = currentSheet.getLastColumn()
  var rows = currentSheet.getRange(2,1,1,lastC).getValues();

  var rowsCSV = rows.join("\n");
  Logger.log("Check This"+" "+rowsCSV);
  var data = Utilities.newBlob(rowsCSV, 'application/octet-stream')

  // Create the data upload job.
  var job = {
    configuration: {
      load: {
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: datasetId,
          tableId: tableId
        },
        skipLeadingRows: 1
      }
    }
  };
  job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, data);
  Logger.log('Load job started. Check on the status of it here: ' +
      'https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/jobs/%s', projectId);
}
```