# Export Google spreadsheet to text file using script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, export-to-text

I have a Google spreadsheet file containing just one sheet with one column. Everytime it is changed, it should be saved as a simple text (*.txt) file on my Google drive. So I would use the "on edit" trigger to run the script.

I found a few scripts that supposedly once did exactly what I need, but they seem to use outdated references, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358683/export-spreadsheet-or-csv-text-file-from-google-drive-forms-using-script/22559489#22559489) which was posted two years ago.
So my question is, how to export a sheet to text file now, in 2016?

Answer (score 10):

Here is a simple export function that works for me: it exports the current sheet as tab-delimited text file, whose name includes the date of creation.

You can set it to be triggered on edit using Resources > Current Project's Triggers in the Script Editor.

```
function export() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var text = values.map(function (a) {return a.join('\t');}).join('\n');
  DriveApp.createFile('Data as of ' + new Date(), text);
}
```

Depending on your editor/OS, you may want `join('\r\n')` instead of  `join('\n')` here.

Comment: Thank you, this got me on the right track. I added a delete-old-file-line (just want one file) and an \r to the delimiter (so in a text file, everything isn't just one long line), and it works perfectly for me:  
  
    function export() {  
  
    DriveApp.getFilesByName('testfile.txt').next().setTrashed(true);  
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  
    var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  
    var text = values.map(function (a) {return a.join('\t');}).join('\r\n');  
    DriveApp.createFile('testfile.txt', text, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);  
}