# Open Google Apps Spreadsheet by name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

With a script I create a new Google Spreadsheet every day.  I'm certain there is only one spreadsheet on the drive with this name, as I trash everything with the same name before creating a new one.

But how can I open the spreadsheet with google apps script? I have no ID for the file. I have a small script so I can find the file:

```
function myFunction() {
 // Log the name of every file in the user's Drive.
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('datafile');
while (files.hasNext()) {
var file = files.next();
Logger.log(file.getName());
}
}
```

Is it possible to open this spreadsheet at all with a script? I want to download it everyday on a server as csv file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `PropertiesService` to store the id of the spreadsheet when you create it:

```
var id = newSS.getId(); //where newSS is your new spreadsheet
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('id', id);
```

You can then call the stored property when you want it:

```
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('id');
```

For more information, check out the [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can open a spreadsheet, having the corresponding file object.

```
function myFunction() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('datafile');
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(file); 
    // do something with spreadsheet
  }
}
```

References:

- [open(file)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openfile) documentation
- [Export Google spreadsheet to text file using script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36756045)